# Fetching data from mongoDB and displaying on HTML

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm having trouble understanding how to fetch data from the MongoDB database and display it on HTML. I already have set for the data.

this is the the server.js file.

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();


//map global promise - get rid of warning
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// connect to  mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/peppino-calc', {
  useMongoClient: true
})
.then(() => { console.log('MongoDB connected...')})
.catch(err => console.log(err));

//Load salaryModel
require('./modles/Idea.js');
const Idea = mongoose.model('ideas');


//body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())


// post history page
app.get('/history', (req, res) => {
  Idea.find({})
  .sort({date:'desc'})
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/js/newJs/history.html')
})

 //process form
 app.post('/ideas', (req, res) => {
   let errors = [];
   if(errors.length > 0) {
     console.log(errors[0]);
   } else {
    const newUser = {
       amount: req.body.totalamount,
       hours: req.body.totalhours,
       salary: req.body.totalsalary,
       tip: req.body.totaltip,
       date: req.body.datetotal
     }
     new Idea(newUser)
     .save()
     .then(idea => {
       res.redirect('/history');
     })
   }
 });

 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './js/newJs')));
 app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5700);

 var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
   console.log('listening on port ', server.address().port);
 });
```

my goal is to display the data from the database in a specific html page.
any help?

Comment: Uhm, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a [template engine](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) in order to display data in an html page, there are many template engines, you can choose one from this [link](https://github.com/expressjs/express/wiki#template-engines)

Here is an example using [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html):

1- install pug

```
npm install pug --save
```

2- set view directory:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

3- set pug as the default view engine

```
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
```

4- create `history.pug` inside `views` folder

```
doctype html
html
    head
    body
        table
            thead
                tr
                    th Name
                    th date
            tbody
                each idea in ideas
                    tr
                        td= idea.name
                        td= idea.date
```

5- pass data from express to pug:

```
app.get('/history', (req, res) => {
    let ideas = Idea.find({})
    .sort({date:'desc'}).exec( (err, ideas) => {
        res.render('history', ideas);
    });
})
```